# Iterating through props to plot markers in a react google map?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I'm working with React Google Maps. I'm trying to obtain the latitude and longitude coordinates for all my contracts so I can plot each contract as a marker on a Google Map.

This is the code I have that's currently working:

```
       <GoogleMap
        googleMapURL={ props.googleMapURL }
        loadingElement={ <div style={ { height: "100%" } } /> }
        containerElement={ <div style={ { height: "400px", width: "350px" } } /> }
        mapElement={ <div style={ { height: "400px", width: "400px" } } 
        /> }
        zoom={12}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
       >
      <Marker 
        position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng  }}
        icon={ iconfilepath }
        />
        </GoogleMap>
```

The above code generates a map for each contract and that's not what I want.

This is what I tried to plot all the markers in one Google map:

```
 <GoogleMap
        googleMapURL={ props.googleMapURL }
        loadingElement={ <div style={ { height: "100%" } } /> }
        containerElement={ <div style={ { height: "400px", width: "350px" } } /> }
        mapElement={ <div style={ { height: "400px", width: "400px" } } /> }
        zoom={12}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
      >
      <MarkerClusterer
        averageCenter
        enableRetinaIcons
        gridSize={60}            
        >
       {props.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.id}
          icon={ iconfilepath }
          position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
        />
       ))}         
      </MarkerClusterer>
      </GoogleMap>
```

Can anyone tell me why the above isn't working?

Comment: you need to `return` your marker. i.e. `return <Marker .... `

Comment: yes this code blob is inside my return statement

Comment: no you mistake what I am saying.  `{props.map(marker => ( return <Marker ...and so on )}`

Comment: that didn't resolve the issue

Comment: the error I get in my console is `TypeError: props.map is not a function`

Comment: This means that `props` is not an array or does not exist. Can you share the full code of the file. From the top of my head this becomes difficult but it might be this `{this.props.map(...all the rest....`

Comment: I tried that and get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Comment: before when I did just one marker `<Marker 
        position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng  }}
        icon={ iconfilepath }
        />` it worked

Comment: so you should pass an array of markers in props and do `{props.markers.map(....` and not pass the `lat` and `lng` of just one.

Comment: Here is my implementation. May help. (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Sprint/tree/master/gmap/client/src)